# Is it possible in python to store a time counter inside a database that counts down, when the counter is stop, it will be able to call some API?

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

**Is it possible in python programming to store a time counter inside a database that counts down, and when the counter is about to run down, it will be able to call some API and change a particular person record update on my API...**

i am reach some website but it's not a my solution

like:

1.[click and check](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/event-scheduler.html)

please give me suggestion

Thank's in advance .. :)

Comment: Databases are for storing information. You can run a different thread, or even a `cron` job for doing what you are saying. Is there a particular reason you want this to be run from the database?

Comment: ok i will try cron

Answer (score 0):

you and write a handler and monitor that particular  table in DB and return the status result if it satisfies that condition